# Using psql to run an update

Tags: database, postgresql

I've a table with two columns are a unique key together and i cannot change the schema.

I'm trying to execute an update using psql in which i change the value of one of the column that are key. The script is similar to the following:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE t1 SET P1='23' where P1='33';
UPDATE t1 SET P1='23' where P1='55';
COMMIT;
```

Using psql with the command:

```
psql -U user -f file
```

I've got the error

```
ERROR: duplicate key violates unique constraint "<key_name>"
```

But the column is in key with another column and changing it doesn't "break" any unique constraint. **The same query inside pgAdmin3 runs fine with no errors**.

I'm not a dba it seems to me that i'm missing something obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, and if you:

```
select idnazione, nextego 
from partitaiva 
where partitaiva='02469480244' 
order by idnazione, nextego;
```

you don't get any duplicate rows?

are you doing

```
BEGIN;
...
COMMIT;
```

when using pgadmin as well?

Comment: I found the error, i wasn't doing BEGIN .. COMMIT in pgAdmin.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Can you type the following in psql and add the output to your question?

```
\d schema.table
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output:

```
              Tabella "public.partitaiva"

    Colonna     |          Tipo          | Modificatori

----------------+------------------------+--------------

 id             | bigint                 | not null

 idnazione      | bigint                 | not null

 partitaiva     | character varying(20)  | not null

 logicaldelete  | boolean                |

 prevego        | bigint                 |

 nextego        | bigint                 | not null

 lastmodified   | bigint                 |

 creationuser   | character varying(255) |

 creationtime   | bigint                 |

 lastmodifyuser | character varying(255) |

 version        | bigint                 |

Indici:

    "partitaiva_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

    "partitaiva_idnazione_key" UNIQUE, btree (idnazione, partitaiva, nextego)

Vincoli di integrità referenziale

    "fk2659231b8f0d2c9" FOREIGN KEY (idnazione) REFERENCES nazione(id)
```

The two columns idnazione and partitaiva are the keys (together with nextego but this is always equal to -1).

Answer (score 0):

The real update statement is:

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE partitaiva SET partitaiva='02469480244' WHERE partitaiva='80911556878';
UPDATE partitaiva SET partitaiva='02469480244' WHERE partitaiva='75545502025';
UPDATE partitaiva SET partitaiva='02469480244' WHERE partitaiva='11056297226';

COMMIT;
```

The column "idnazione" is different in every row and more important the same statement in pgAdmin3 runs fine.